# Comparing floating point for sort ascending

Tags: c

I have this structure:

```
typedef struct _Preset Preset;
struct _Preset
{
    gfloat freq;
};
```

I want to be able to sort ascending.
I write this function to compare using integers "lexicographically ordered" for checking whether two floating point numbers are close to each other:

```
gint comp_func_sort_float(Preset *ps1, Preset *ps2)
{
    gint freq1, freq2;

    freq1 = *(int*)&ps1->freq;
    freq2 = *(int*)&ps2->freq;

    return (freq1 - freq2);
}
```

I want to compare using limited precision:

```
gint comp_func_sort_float(float A, float B)
{
    int dif;

    assert(sizeof(float) == sizeof(int));

    if (A == B)
        return 0;

    dif = abs(*(int*)&A - *(int*)&B);

    if (dif <= 0.25f)
        return 0;

    return -1;
}
```

Exist another way to do this.

Comment: Casting a pointer to a `float` to a pointer to `int` and then dereference that pointer will not work very well. You will not get a value remotely close to the actual value, unless `int` and `glfloat` are stored in the same format, which they aren't. In fact, what you have with that piece of code is [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: "Another" is the wrong word because the one you have makes no sense as a comparison function.  A clue is that it never returns a negative number.

Comment: @Gene: Well, at least the second "optional" way is marginally better.

Comment: We may need more details. `gint` and `gfloat` aren't standard types, what library are we talking about? Glib? Something in-house? Is there any reason to be casting pointers and dereferencing?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg IEEE 754 floats can be safely compared as signed integers, so long as the float values are finite, and the integer type you're using is the right size and endianness.

Comment: `if (dif <= 0.25f)` would not expected to ever be true as `dif` has only `int` values 0 or more.  Further `if (A == B)` precludes `dif` getting a zero value.

Comment: @duskwuff Yes, but the OP isn't comparing straight floats with straight ints, the pointer-casting and dereferencing will cause undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you get the proper size and endian-ness, 2's complement, IEEE [binary32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary32) etc., overlaying an `int` over `float` does not give the same numeric order.  The bit interpretation of a `float` is more like sign-magnitude than 2's complement.

Suggest:

```
gint comp_func_sort_float(float A, float B)
  return (A > B) - (A < B);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are reading the `float`s as `int`s, and so you effectively compare the IEEE 754 *notation*, rather than the float values.

Since you are effectively comparing 'integers', the `dif` test is totally useless. First of all, your *input* is cast to integers. Next, you are using `abs`, which returns an integer even if the input is float. Finally, `dif` itself is an integer as well, and while the comparison to a float value is valid, it will most certainly not do anything useful at that point.

I also wonder why you switch from using pointers in `comp_func_sort_float(Preset *ps1, Preset *ps2)` to immediate arguments in `comp_func_sort_float(float A, float B)`. I will assume the pointer notation is the proper one, as it should be for `qsort` and equivalent functions.

This works correctly, treating a difference of +/-0.25 as 'equal' and returning the correct integer (-1, 0, 1) for all comparisons:

```
int comp_func_sort_float(const void *Aa, const void *Bb)
{
    float A = *(float *)Aa, B = *(float *)Bb;
    float dif;

    dif = A - B;

    if (dif <= -0.25f)
        return -1;
    if (dif >= 0.25f)
        return 1;

    return 0;
}
```